# AWS CDK stack.regionalFact is not a function

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am working with AWS CDK for typescript.
I have my stack which consists of only one role

```
export class ModelServingStack extends BaseStack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, props: StackCommonProps, stackConfig: any) {
    const role: iam.IRole = this.createIamRole(`ModelEndpoint-Role`);
  }

  private createIamRole(roleBaseName: string): iam.IRole {
    return new iam.Role(this, "MyRole", {
      assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal("sns.amazonaws.com"),
    });
  }
}
```

When I run the command to deploy `cdk deploy` I get the following error:

```
/workspaces/Zeus/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-iam/lib/principals.ts:540
    return stack.regionalFact(
                 ^
TypeError: Resolution error: Resolution error: Resolution error: Resolution error: stack.regionalFact is not a function.
Object creation stack:
  at stack traces disabled.
Object creation stack:
  at stack traces disabled..
    at ServicePrincipalToken.resolve (/workspaces/Zeus/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-iam/lib/principals.ts:540:18)
    at RememberingTokenResolver.resolveToken (/workspaces/Zeus/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/resolvable.ts:80:24)
    at RememberingTokenResolver.resolveToken (/workspaces/Zeus/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/private/resolve.ts:286:18)
    at resolve (/workspaces/Zeus/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/private/resolve.ts:212:51)
    at Object.resolve [as mapToken] (/workspaces/Zeus/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/private/resolve.ts:119:77)
    at TokenizedStringFragments.mapTokens (/workspaces/Zeus/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/string-fragments.ts:65:33)
    at RememberingTokenResolver.resolveString (/workspaces/Zeus/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/resolvable.ts:99:22)
    at RememberingTokenResolver.resolveString (/workspaces/Zeus/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/private/resolve.ts:290:23)
    at resolve (/workspaces/Zeus/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/private/resolve.ts:170:48)
    at Object.resolve (/workspaces/Zeus/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/private/resolve.ts:119:77)
```

### Edit

The problem was a mismatch between the `aws-cdk` packages installed and the `cdk` global package.
Make sure to have both updated to the latest version.